# How to get SMO object (e.g Table) from SQl SERVER object_id?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, smo

How to get SMO object (e.g Table) from sql server object_id?

I see that it is possible to pop up SMO object by URN (Server.GetSmoObject method). 
But then I got another question: how to convert object_id to URN?

Comment: I've edited my answer. It might help in other ways.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That is, selecting an object by object_id seems an odd thing to do in SMO. What is your use case?

Comment: I wanted to know how to select objects by id because 1) I'm trying to make scripts more compact 2) I'm learning SMO and mapping my knowledge to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume here that you are using C#, and with that your server variable is already connected etc.

If you know what object you are looking for (in the example a Table), try this.

```
Server.GetSmoObject(Server.Database["DBName"].Tables.ItemById(object_id).Urn);
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Here is another way. It creates a Datatable which have 4 columns. ObjectsType, Schema, Name and Urn

```
DataTable table = server.Databases["DBName"].EnumObjects();
foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
{
    if(item[2].ToString() == "Companies" && item[0].ToString() == "Table")
    {
        server.GetSmoObject(item[3].ToString());
    }
}
```

But if you want to create a Urn in SQL Code you can do something like

```
Select '"Server[@Name=''' + @@SERVERNAME + ''']/Database[@Name=''' + DB_Name() + '''/Table[@Name=''' + OBJECT_NAME(117575457) + ''']"'
```

Comment: Of course with this solution I should know in advance that object_id represents the table (not view), but this is enough for me.